# How to convert a double into a char*

Tags: c++, char, double, type-conversion

I am heavily struggling with a question which should be very easy: how do I do a simple type conversion (from `double` into `char*`) in basic C.

I have found quite some solutions, but they are all based on conversions from `double` to `char[x]`, but I am working here with `char*`, not with `char[]`. (I don't know how long the resulting string will be).

On top of that, I really can't believe that another type (be it `stringstream`, `std::strings`, ...) are needed for something that simple.

I admit, I'm a complete newbie in basic C, but I have worked in other languages (Visual Basic, Delphi, Java, ...) and I just can't understand why I can't find a simple function like "to_char_pointer(double d)" to do this.

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: The better question is what are you trying to do? A double cannot be converted to a char*.

If you're simply trying to get a string representation of the double, you're going to have to convert it to a char array. A function accepting a char* will accept a char[].

Comment: Sorry, I was quite stressed when I wrote this question: it seems that I have access to STL library and as such my problem has been solved:
`#include <string>`<br/>
`using namespace std;`<br/>
<br/>
`string str = to_string((long double)vector_with_doubles->at(i));`<br/>

Hence this question can indeed be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sprintf()` as you have done to convert a `double` into a `string`, but I would actually recommend using `_snprintf()` instead simply because `sprintf()` has no regard for the fact that strings are fixed length devices in memory and will overflow if you don't watch it. `_snprintf()` allows you to specify the length of the out string, just be sure to specify the size as one less than the actual allocated memory block, because `_snprintf()` does not store the terminating null character if it has to cut the output short.

An example us using `_snprintf()` is:

```
void ToString(char * outStr, int length, double val)
{
     _snprintf(outStr,length,"%f",val);
}
```

Comment: Using `snprintf()` (standard C function) rather than `_snprintf()` (non-standard C function) is certainly more portable.  Using either instead of `sprintf()` to prevent overrun is a good first step, but checking the function's result and handling that is a necessary part missing here.